# Get number of bytes sent from the beginning of the script

Tags: php

If you're to send proper `Content-Length` header, you might want to use this:

```
ob_start();                       //Start a buffer 
echo "Some output\n";             //Send output in buffer
$size = ob_get_length();          //Get length of data in buffer
header("Content-Length: $size");  //Send proper header

//Send data and exit
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
exit;
```

Is there a way to get the number of characters sent even without using the output buffer? (I understand that if something was sent, you cannot use `header` anymore)

Comment: I think the answer is `no`.

Comment: Only if instead of _outputting_ your content, you assemble it in a string variable first – then you can measure it’s length, send your header, and output the variable’s content afterwards. But I doubt that’s more efficient than using the output buffer in the first place, and since it requires you to put _every_ output into that variable, it makes it more complex to use reasonably structured (HTML) templates as well.